# Passar parametro value ao clicar em input type radio, com php, jquery e mysql propagando

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Ola, boa tarde a todos, pessoal estou com uma duvida não sei como proceder preciso enviar o valor que esta dentro do value input type radio para uma variavel jquery lembrando que ate consegui mas so funciona la primeira da lista que foi propagada com mysql.`

```js
        <script type='text/javascript' >

    $(function(){
 $('#sbt_click1').click(function() {
 var id = $(this).val();
 alert( 'Chegou o id: '+ id );
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"functions/ass_arm_session_id_asso.php?id="+id,
  dataType:"text",
 
 
});
});
});
</script>
```

```html
 <?php
$sql_lista = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM ass_log as c1 
inner join ass_associado as c2 on c2.id_ass = c1.log_associado 
inner join ass_at_des as c3 on c3.id_at_des = c1.log_at_des");
while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($sql_lista)){
          ?>
<INPUT TYPE="RADIO" name="sbt_click1" id="sbt_click1" VALUE="<?php echo $resultado['id_ass'];?>"><?php } ?>
```

`se alguem souber como faço para enviar pois não consegui acionar as demais

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link, creio que vai encontrar a resposta pro seu erro
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não pode conter Ids repetidos no html, então você pode corrigir usando classes da seguinte forma:

Troque

```
$('#sbt_click1')
```

por

```
$('.sbt_click1')
```

e troque:

```
id="sbt_click1"
```

POR

```
class="sbt_click1"
```

Acredito que isso resolva.

Comment: cara muito obrigado foi falta de atenção rsrs estou a mais de 12 horas sem descanso, vou parar agora valew amigo